# Installing Meteor - Couldn't write the launcher script

Tags: frameworks, terminal, meteor

I am front-end developer attempting to crossover into the world of web app development. I've come a long way in learning Javascript, and now I'm looking to toy around with frameworks.

I still have a bit to learn about using the OSX terminal, but I was hoping somebody could help me with this first stumble I'm having....

**I try to install meteor using:**

$ curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh

**Then I get the following:**

Meteor 0.6.4 has been installed in your home directory (~/.meteor).
Writing a launcher script to /usr/local/bin/meteor for your convenience.
This may prompt for your password.
cp: /usr/local/bin/meteor: No such file or directory

Couldn't write the launcher script. Please either:

  (1) Run the following as root:
        cp ~/.meteor/tools/latest/launch-meteor /usr/bin/meteor
  (2) Add ~/.meteor to your path, or
  (3) Rerun this command to try again.

Then to get started, take a look at 'meteor --help' or see the docs at
docs.meteor.com.

Comment: Have you tried something from those 3 options? :)

Answer (score 6):

If it's still helpful to anyone, going into /usr/local/bin, running "sudo rm meteor" then running the install gets it to work for me

Answer (score 0):

Yeah try one of the three suggestions or:

sudo curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh

Comment: That's where I was stuck....

1. cp: /usr/bin/meteor: Permission denied
2. Don't understand what it's asking me to do
3. Re-run which command?

Comment: 1. When you run a command as root, you put "sudo" in front of it. Like this: "$ sudo cp ~/.meteor/tools/latest/launch-meteor /usr/bin/meteor" 2. Have you tried to google it? 3. Rerun "$ curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem heres how I fixed it!

1. Delete all meteor folders
   In finder (cmd +shft+g)
     type in "~/.meteor"
     on the top of the finder window where is has the folder.meteor click and drag folder to trash
2. In finder (cmd +shft+g) type in "/usr/bin/meteor" then drag the meteor folder to trash
   3.In /usr/ create a new folder "local" (password required) and inside "local" create a folder "bin"
3. Go back to terminal a run curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh