# Installing Meteor-Permission Denied/Run 'meteor update'

Tags: meteor

I was having the same problems to this post [Installing Meteor - Couldn't write the launcher script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156736/installing-meteor-couldnt-write-the-launcher-script) tried all the suggestions and got stuck with:

*The latest version of Meteor, 0.6.4, is already installed on this
computer. Run 'meteor update' inside of a particular project
directory to update that project to Meteor 0.6.4.*

So I went ~/.meteor [I have these options: meteor,(Folders( packages, releases, tools))]

clicked on meteor and got this:

*$ /Users/Josh/.meteor/tools/cc18dfef9e/bin/meteor ; exit;
run: You're not in a Meteor project directory.
To create a new Meteor project:
   meteor create 
For example:
   meteor create myapp
For more help, see 'meteor --help'.
logout
[Process completed]*

I tried deleting the .meteor folder and reinstalling and the same thing happend.

Note: /usr/bin/sh/ (cannot be found)

Comment: I had the same problem heres how I fixed it!

 1. Delete all meteor folders
    In finder (cmd +shft+g)
      type in "~/.meteor"
      on the top of the finder window where is has the folder.meteor click and drag folder to trash
 2. In finder (cmd +shft+g) type in "/usr/bin/meteor" then drag the meteor folder to trash
 3.In /usr/ create a new folder "local" (password required) and inside "local" create a folder "bin"
 4. Go back to terminal a run curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh

Comment: Go to your application project's folder and run `meteor update` there, not in meteor installation folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Delete all meteor folders In finder (cmd +shft+g) type in "~/.meteor" on the top of the finder window where is has the folder.meteor click and drag folder to trash 2. In finder (cmd +shft+g) type in "/usr/bin/meteor" then drag the meteor folder to trash 3.In /usr/ create a new folder "local" (password required) and inside "local" create a folder "bin" 4. Go back to terminal a run curl install.meteor.com | /bin/sh –